# Why Incompatible type when trying to call a void function in main

Tags: c

My program is quite simple, but I can't understand why I get this error message.

This is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( ){
    TriangularNumber();
}

//gets a range of numbers as input and prints all triangular numbers in range.

void TriangularNumber(){
int left,right,tempSquare;
scanf("%d", &left);
scanf("%d", &right);

for(int i=left;i<=right;i++){
    tempSquare = 8*i + 1;
    for(int j = 0;j<=tempSquare;j++){
        if(tempSquare = j*j){
            printf("%d is a triangular number",tempSquare);
        }                
    }
}
```

This is my error message when compiling:

> ex2.c:10 error: incompatible types for redefinition of 'TriangularNumber'

I simply want the void function to do her thing, I'm doing an assignment with many completely different tasks and I want them to be separated instead of one messy main method.

Comment: You either need to prototype methods above your main, or implement main as the last method in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under older versions of C, if the compiler sees a function *call* before it sees either a declaration or definition for that function, it will assume that the function returns an `int`.  So what's happening is:

```
int main()
{
  TriangularNumber( ); // no declaration or definition visible before this,
                       // compiler assumes TriangularNumber returns int
                       // (i.e., TriangularNumber is *implicitly* declared
                       // to return int)
  ...
}

void TriangularNumber( ) // Definition of TriangularNumber has different 
{                        // return type from the *implied* declaration
                         // above, compiler gets upset because the types 
                         // don't match.
```

As of C99, this is no longer the case - implicit `int` is no longer allowed.  Under a C99 compiler, you would get a different error along the lines of "TriangularNumber has not been declared before use".

A function *declaration* must be visible before the function may be called.  A function definition also serves as a declaration, so the easiest way to fix this is to move the definition of `TriangularNumber` before `main`:

```
void TriangularNumber( void )
{
  ...
}

int main( void )
{
  TriangularNumber( );
  ...
}
```

If `TriangularNumber` is defined in a separate source file, then you wouldn't be able to do this; you'd need a separate declaration somewhere before its call in `main`.  You'd typically set up a separate header file with any declarations like so:

```
/**
 * t.h - header file for TriangularNumber module
 */
#ifndef T_H
#define T_H

void TriangularNumber( void );

#endif

/**
 * t.c - implementation file for TriangularNumber module
 */
#include "t.h" // include the declaration; in case we've made a mistake
               // and have a mismatch between the declaration and definition,
               // we can catch that here as the compiler will yell at us

void TriangularNumber( void )
{
  ...
}

/** 
 * main.c - source file that needs to use TriangularNumber module
 */
#include "t.h" // makes sure declaration for TriangularNumber is visible

int main( void )
{
  TriangularNumber( );
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void TriangularNumber();

int main( ){
    TriangularNumber();
}

//gets a range of numbers as input and prints all triangular numbers in 


void TriangularNumber(){
    int left,right,tempSquare;
    scanf("%d", &left);
    scanf("%d", &right);

    for(int i=left;i<=right;i++){
        tempSquare = 8*i + 1;
        for(int j = 0;j<=tempSquare;j++){
            if(tempSquare == j*j){
                printf("%d is a triangular number\n",tempSquare);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```